# Separation in the q-shifted factorial

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, q-series

Is their any formula to separate the power in 
$$(q^{x+y};q)_n$$

where $(a;q)_n=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1-aq^i)$ denotes the $q$-shifted factorial.

P.S: $x,y$ and $n$ are all integers.

I'm glade for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what "separate the power" means.  Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this as
\begin{align}
(q^{x + y}; q)_n &= \prod_{i = 0}^{n - 1} (1 - q^{x + y}q^i) \\
&= \prod_{j = x}^{n + x - 1} (1 - q^yq^j) \qquad (\text{where }j = i + x) \\
&= \frac{\prod_{j = 0}^{n + x - 1} (1 - q^yq^j)}{\prod_{j = 0}^{x - 1} (1 - q^yq^j)} \\
&= \frac{(q^y;q)_{n + x}}{(q^y;q)_x}.
\end{align}

Another option is
$$ (q^{x + y};q)_n = \frac{(q;q)_{n+x+y-1}}{(q;q)_{x+y-1}}. $$

But I don't think you can separate $x$ and $y$ any more so that you can separate them in $(x + y)!$. After all,

$$ (q;q)_n = [n]_q!(1 - q)^{n} $$

so what you have is

$$ (q^{x + y};q)_n = \frac{[n + x + y -1]_q!}{[x + y - 1]_q!}(1-q)^n.$$

Comment: i really appreciate your answer Mr @T.Gunn. But can i use this identity 
$$(aq^n;q)_k=\frac{(a;q)_k(aq^k;q)_n}{(a;q)_k}$$
and replacing $a$ by $q^x$ and $n$ by $y$ ?

Comment: @othmane Try it and see. Although something is off in your formula because you have a factor of $(a;q)_k$ in both the numerator and denominator.